# perform a function for a specified variable time peroid automatically

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

i have a function and that is to be carried out for a specified value of time. I have used set interval function, but i need a variable time that is fetched from the database as timeout period.
In getInactiveTimePeriod iam getting the time from browser local storage and is stored as a result of Api call.
time is getting in timeInMilliseconds as expected.
my code is as follows.

```
<script>
var timeInMilliseconds;
window.setInterval(function() {
       getInactiveTimePeriod();
 } , 10000);

 function getInactiveTimePeriod() {
  chrome.storage.local.get("user_inactive_time", function (obj) {
     var timeInMinuts = obj.user_inactive_time;
     timeInMilliseconds = timeInMinuts *(60000);

});
 }
 getInactiveTimePeriod();
 checkUserInactivity();

 function checkUserInactivity() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       // code
   }, timeInMilliseconds);
 }
 checkUserInactivity();
</script>
```

in this the function only works for one time. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: `$variable` is undefined. What do you mean "fetched from database"? Where and how is it fetched? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: This doesn't explain at all how you define `$variable` :/ Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Currently, here's what this code does : 1. Creates an interval that assigns the the same undefined value ($variable)  to the same variable (timeInMilliseconds) every 10000ms. 2. Assigns an undefined value ($variable) to timeInMilliseconds (and then again every 10000ms). 3. Executes twice checkUserInactivity(), which sets a timeout, which means you launch and execute two timeouts. Bottom line : I have no idea what you're trying to do :)

Comment: actually iam getting a time from database and is stored in the browser storage and is getting in the variable timeInMilliseconds in every 10000 ms.

it might be 25000, or 26000 etc.
i want checkUserInactivity to be carried out in that interval the pblm is that timeInMilliseconds varies according to the value in db .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should receive your value from the database and then proceed with setTimeout function.
It can be done in a next way:

```
<script>
window.setInterval(() => {
    getInactiveTimePeriod(); //every 10 seconds this function will be run
}, 10000);

function getInactiveTimePeriod() {
    var timeInMilliseconds = $variable; // time value fetched from database
    //use arrow functions to be in one scope
    setTimeout(() => { 
        // code
    }, timeInMilliseconds); //code execution will be delayed according to timeInMilliseconds
}
</script>
```

I believe it should help

Comment: iam sorry i have a doubt. in this the function getInactiveTimePeriod() will work for every 10000 millisec.
i have a large code inside checkUserInactivity and it is to be carried out in other time interval might be 250000 milli sec.
when i write this code inside getInactiveTimePeriod() as you suggest does all this carried out in 10000 ms.